# Update EF5 Model ConnectionString in Runtime

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have winforms app with SQL Db on my localServer. I added EF5 using Database_First.
The question is:
How to change the connection string of EF5 Model in "Runtime" using "OpenFileDialog"?

I want to provide the app with a "Feature" to let the client specify his Database Server where the app db is located.

Comment: You can't choose a database server by an open file dialog. What exactly do you mean?

Comment: @GertArnold you are right, but I meant I want to let the client to choose his "SQL Server" in Runtime. So the connection string should be changed in App.Config automatically.

Comment: Is it so hard to answer my question?

Comment: look at the example given here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entityclient.entityconnectionstringbuilder.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems that need to be considered. 
First DbContext has constructor that takes a user defined connection string, but this constructor is not exposed in the generated code for your context, so you have to add it in a partial file outside of the generated code. 
And then the Entity Framework connection string itself differs from a typical SqlClient connection string, so you have to use [EntityConnectionStringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entityclient.entityconnectionstringbuilder.aspx) to build an appropriate connection string.

For example consider this sample code:

```
public partial class MyContext: DbContext
{
    public MyContext(string efConnectionString):base(efConnectionString)
    {

    }

    public static MyContext CreateContextFromAdoCS(string adoConnectionString)
    {
        EntityConnectionStringBuilder entityBuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();

        //Set the provider name.
        entityBuilder.Provider = "System.Data.SqlClient";

        // Set the provider-specific connection string.
        entityBuilder.ProviderConnectionString = adoConnectionString;

        // Set the Metadata location.
        entityBuilder.Metadata = @"res://*/MyModel.csdl|
                        res://*/MyModel.ssdl|
                        res://*/MyModel.msl";
        var efCs = entityBuilder.ToString();

        return new MyContext(efCs);
    }
}
```

If you have an existing SqlClient connection string you can use the factory method to create an instance of your context.

Here [Display a ConnectionString dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6895251/display-a-connectionstring-dialog) you can see how to open a standard dialog to construct an SqlClient connection string.

Answer (score 0):

Let it be in App.config

```
<add name="ConnectionStringNew" connectionString="Data Source=ServerName;user id=sa;Password=sasa;initial catalog=[DataBase]" />
```

Have a Combobox where you want to let the user to select the DataBase.

FIll the combobox with below coding.

```
SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection (ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionStringNew"].ConnectionString);

SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NAME) AS ID,NAME FROM SYS.SYSDATABASES WHERE DBID > 4 ORDER BY NAME", con);

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(comm);                
da.Fill(dtblDataBase);

cmbDataBase.DataSource = dtblDataBase;  
cmbDataBase.ValueMember = "ID";  
cmbDataBase.DisplayMember = "NAME";
```

Replace the DataBase Name Like below.

```
DataBaseName = Convert.ToString(con1.ConnectionString);
CommonVariables.strDataBaseName = DataBaseName.Replace("[DataBase]",      cmbDataBase.Text.Trim());
CommonVariables.strCompanyName = cmbDataBase.Text.Trim();
```

I have just given a coding sample.. Customize it as you want.

Comment: Your code for the old ADO.Net, I want something for the new ADO.Net Entity Framework 5.