# Premade SQL Server authentication dialog

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, authentication, controls

I need to offer users to enter SQL credentials in a WinForm application, where they can select Windows Authentication or SQL Server authentication, specify the server name and a user name and password if appropriate.

Obviously I could do this myself, but it feels like a problem that should have a pre-canned solution out there. However my Google skills have proven inadequate to find one. Does anyone know of one?

Something like the controls on this dialog (although I happen to not need the server type or the advanced options):

[image: SQL Server 2014 dialog]

Comment: There's nothing in the framework to do this. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6895251/display-a-connectionstring-dialog) might get you further.

Comment: I don't know of any, probably because it is so easy to recreate. Since you already need some customization, it's probably best to create your own.

Comment: @DavidLibido, It is easy enough, I just hate reinventing the wheel. It has to have been done a hundred times already ...