# Where to get Windows.VisualStudio.Data?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

Hello I'm am beginning with visual studio and C#

I saw a very nice thread here: [Display a ConnectionString dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6895251/display-a-connectionstring-dialog/6895428#6895428)

Sadly the Link for the sample code is dead

Either way I need to use the object : DataConnectionDialog

this object is in the Windows.VisualStudio.Data namespace. Where can I Include that it's not there in the add reference window.  Where can I download that.

I am using VS community 2013

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add reference to Microsoft.Data.ConnectionUI.Dialog.dll which can be found under
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Microsoft.Data.ConnectionUI.Dialog.dll

```
Microsoft.Data.ConnectionUI.DataConnectionDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Data.ConnectionUI.DataConnectionDialog();
        Microsoft.Data.ConnectionUI.DataSource.AddStandardDataSources(dlg);          
        if (Microsoft.Data.ConnectionUI.DataConnectionDialog.Show(dlg) == DialogResult.OK)
        {

        }
```

Comment: I doubt that file is redistributable.

Comment: alternatively you can download using Nuget Package Manager; just search for Microsoft Data Connection Dialog. or you can go to https://www.nuget.org/packages/DataConnectionDialog/1.2.0 you can also check license here.