# DbProviderFactory using Data Connection UI

Tags: c#

I'm trying to use the DDEX Data Connection UI from Microsoft:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb163928.aspx

But I can't seem to find any example C# code on how to run it.  Specifically, I am looking to implement a `DbProviderFactory`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd0w4a2z.aspx

to create the right connection.  Is it the same as the Nuget DataConnectionDialog here?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32326126/3661120

If so, how do I'd like to implement the code described in the bottom part of this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13134064/3661120

but I don't know how to parse out the `driver` name, when all the dialog box does is return the `ConnectionString`.

Comment: If anyone is interested, you can pull the `DataProvider` string needed for the `DbProviderFactory` from `DataConnectionDialog.SelectedDataProvider.Name`.